# How do I get correct answers using my code with the barycentric formula?

Tags: c++

My function `getHeightOfTerrain()` is calling a barycentric formula function that is not returning the correct height for the one set test height in : `heightMapFromArray[][]`.

I've tried watching OpenGL JAVA Game tutorials 14,21, 22, by "thin matrix" and I am confused on how to use my array: `heightMapforBaryCentric` in both of the supplied functions, and how to set the arguments that are passed to the `baryCentic()` function in some sort of manner so that I can solve the problem.

```
int creaateTerrain(int height, int width)
{
    float holderY[6] = { 0.f ,0.f,0.f,0.f,0.f,0.f };
    float scaleit = 1.5f;
    float holder[6] = { 0.f,0.f,0.f,0.f,0.f,0.f };
    for (int z = 0, z2 =0; z < iterationofHeightMap;z2++)
    {
        //each loop is two iterations and creates one quad (two triangles)
        //however because each iteration is by two (i.e. : x=x+2) om bottom
        //the amount of triangles is half the x value
        //
        //number of vertices : 80 x 80 x 6.

        //column
        for (int x = 0, x2 = 0; x < iterationofHeightMap;x2++) 
        {

            //relevant - A   :  first triangle - on left triangle
            //[row] [colum[]
            holder[0] = heightMapFromArray[z][x];
            //holder[0] = (float)imageData[(z / 2 * MAP_Z + (x / 2)) * 3];
            //holder[0] = holder[0] / 255;// *scaleit;
            vertices.push_back(glm::vec3(x, holder[0], z));
            //match height map with online barycentric use
            heightMapforBaryCentric[x2][z2] = holder[0];

            holder[1] = heightMapFromArray[z+2][x];
            //holder[1] = (float)imageData[(((z + 2) / 2 * MAP_Z + ((x) / 2))) * 3];
            //holder[1] = holder[1] / 255;// 6 * scaleit;
            vertices.push_back(glm::vec3(x, holder[1], z + 2));
            //match height map with online barycentric use
            heightMapforBaryCentric[x2][z2+1] = holder[1];

            holder[2] = heightMapFromArray[z+2][x+2];
            //holder[2] = (float)imageData[(((z + 2) / 2 * MAP_Z + ((x + 2) / 2))) * 3];
            //holder[2] = holder[2] / 255;// *scaleit;
            vertices.push_back(glm::vec3(x + 2, holder[2], z + 2));
            ////match height map with online barycentric use
            heightMapforBaryCentric[x2+1][z2+1] = holder[2];


            //relevant - B  - second  triangle (on right side)

            holder[3] = heightMapFromArray[z][x];
            //holder[3] = (float)imageData[((z / 2)*MAP_Z + (x / 2)) * 3];
            //holder[3] = holder[3] / 255;// 256 * scaleit;
            vertices.push_back(glm::vec3(x, holder[3], z));


            holder[4] = heightMapFromArray[x+2][z+2];
            //holder[4] = (float)imageData[(((z + 2) / 2 * MAP_Z + ((x + 2) / 2))) * 3];
            //holder[4] = holder[4] / 255;// *scaleit;
            vertices.push_back(glm::vec3(x + 2, holder[4], z + 2));

            holder[5] = heightMapFromArray[x+2][z];
            //holder[5] = (float)imageData[((z / 2)*MAP_Z + ((x + 2) / 2)) * 3];
            //holder[5] = holder[5] / 255;// *scaleit;
            vertices.push_back(glm::vec3(x + 2, holder[5], z));
            x = x + 2;
        }
        z = z + 2;
    }
    return(1);
}


float getHeightOfTerrain(float worldX, float worldZ) {


    float terrainX = worldX;
    float terrainZ = worldZ;
    int gridSquareSize = 2.0f;
    gridX = (int)floor(terrainX / gridSquareSize);
    gridZ = (int)floor(terrainZ / gridSquareSize);
    xCoord = ((float)(fmod(terrainX, gridSquareSize)) / (float)gridSquareSize);
    zCoord = ((float)(fmod(terrainZ, gridSquareSize)) / (float)gridSquareSize);

    if (xCoord <= (1 - zCoord)) 
    {

        answer = baryCentric(
        //left triangle
        glm::vec3(0.0f, heightMapforBaryCentric[gridX][gridZ], 0.0f),
        glm::vec3(0.0f, heightMapforBaryCentric[gridX][gridZ+1], 1.0f),
        glm::vec3(1.0f, heightMapforBaryCentric[gridX+1][gridZ+1], 1.0f),
        glm::vec2(xCoord, zCoord));

    //  if (answer != 1)
    //  {
    //      fprintf(stderr, "Z:gridx: %d  gridz: %d  answer: %f\n", gridX, gridZ,answer);
    //      
    //  }
    }
    else
    {
        //right triangle
        answer = baryCentric(glm::vec3(0, heightMapforBaryCentric[gridX][gridZ], 0),
            glm::vec3(1,heightMapforBaryCentric[gridX+1][gridZ+1], 1), 
            glm::vec3(1,heightMapforBaryCentric[gridX+1][gridZ], 0), 
            glm::vec2(xCoord, zCoord));


    }

    if (answer == 1)

    {
        answer = 0;
    }

    //answer = abs(answer - 1);

    return(answer);
}


float baryCentric(glm::vec3 p1, glm::vec3 p2, glm::vec3 p3 , glm::vec2 pos) {
    float det = (p2.z - p3.z) * (p1.x - p3.x) + (p3.x - p2.x) * (p1.z - p3.z);
    float l1 = ((p2.z - p3.z) * (pos.x - p3.x) + (p3.x - p2.x) * (pos.y - p3.z)) / det;
    float l2 = ((p3.z - p1.z) * (pos.x - p3.x) + (p1.x - p3.x) * (pos.y - p3.z)) / det;
    float l3 = 1.0f - l1 - l2;
    return (l1 * p1.y + l2 * p2.y + l3 * p3.y);
}
```

My expected results were that the center of the test grid's height to be the set value .5 and gradually less as the heights declined.  My results were the heights being all the same, varied, or increasing.  Usually these heights were under the value of one.

Comment: Step through the function [with a debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) and see where the program deviates from the expected. Odds are good that's where the bug is.

Comment: Well. I'm unsure if I am calling the barycentric correctly at all, does it look right?  Thank you!